# Variable in another class not changing

Tags: c#, class, variables

I have two files, **class1.cs** and **prologue.cs**. In prologue there is a public bool "Panic".

Prologue.cs

```
public partial class Prologue : Script{

     public bool Panic;

     public void PrologueMission(){ //Called when the script starts
         Panic = true;
     }
```

And in class1.cs I have

```
void Update10(){ //Runs this function every 10 seconds
    Prologue prologue = new Prologue(); //prologue.cs
    if (prologue.Panic) { 
        //code...
    }
}
```

Problem is, bool Panic remains false in Class1.cs, so I created a log method to find out what is happening. Panic becomes true in Prologue.cs but remains false in Class1.cs.

I have tried other ways like a static variable and a method that returns true/false but none of it seemed to work so I'm stuck here.

**In short:** Why is bool Panic set to true in Prologue.cs, but in Class1.cs always remains false.

I hope you can also explain the reason this doesn't work, but any answers are appreciated!

Edit: Log:

```
Prologue: .Panic:True //Set to true in Prologue.cs
prologue.Panic: False //False in class1.cs
prologue.Panic: False //False in class1.cs
prologue.Panic: False //False in class1.cs
Prologue: .Panic:True //Set to true in Prologue.cs again
prologue.Panic: False //False in class1.cs
prologue.Panic: False //False in class1.cs
prologue.Panic: False //False in class1.cs
```

Comment: `PrologueMission()` isn't the constructor for `Prologue`, so isn't run anywhere (at least in the code you have posted)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Panic` is only set to true by calling `PrologueMission`.

You are not calling it.

```
 void Update10(){ //Runs this function every 10 seconds
  Prologue prologue = new Prologue(); //prologue.cs

  prologue.PrologueMission(); // <<<<

  if (prologue.Panic) { 
      //code...
  }
 }
```

---

If you want it to be set initially you would have to do so in the constructor of `Prologue`

```
public partial class Prologue : Script{

    public bool Panic;

    public Prologue()
    {
      Panic = true;
    }

    //...
}
```

which does the same as:

```
public partial class Prologue : Script{

    public bool Panic = true;

    // ...
}
```

---

**As per comments**: You will have to store your Prologe instance outside the update methods:

```
public class Class1
{
   Prologue myPrologue = new Prologue();
   //...
   void AnotherMethod()
   {
     myPrologue.PrologueMission();
   }
   //...
   void Update10()
   {
     if (myPrologue.Panic) 
     { 
        //code...
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: PrologueMission is ran at the very start of the script from an another method in Class1.cs. Update10 runs every 10 seconds. I tried adding your way too, but same result. Thanks anyways.

Comment: you are creating a new Prologe with the call `new Prologue()` It is entirely differnet from the one you used in another update. You will have to move the creation of the prologe to the creation/initialization of your Class1 and KEEP IT (as a variable of the class);

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confusing the Consturctor with your function PrologueMission. You either have to call PrologueMission or make that function your constructor.

Either change the function to be a constructor :

```
public partial class Prologue : Script{

     public bool Panic;

     public Prologue (){ //Called when the script starts
         Panic = true;
     }
```

Or

Call the right function :

```
void Update10(){ //Runs this function every 10 seconds
    Prologue prologue = new Prologue(); //prologue.cs
      prologue.PrologueMission(); // Need this call
    if (prologue.Panic) { 
        //code...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You start your script at the begin. Then you make a new Instance of a dialog in your Update10 function. Since you don't refer to the dialog you made at the beginning, the Panic property remains false.

You have to work with the same dialog everywhere. Make your dialog at the beginning and store it to a variable you can use anywhere.